# ERROR: Type error: `file_path' expected, found `_G409' (a var)

Tags: prolog

I have a problem with my Prolog Program. It is designed to assign words in a made-up language the given nouns/verbs from English.

Now we are getting:

```
ERROR: source_sink `sharks' does not exist ...
ERROR: Type error: 'file_path' expected, found '_G409' (a var)
```

...

```
translation(Nqrrroah, Nqblubh, Nqflua, Nqdwingi,
        Nqlhalha, Ukahama, Mhboa, Sharabrab, Falup) :- 
 ([sharks, goldfishes, hawks, finches, boys, eat, swim, fly],
  [Nqrrroah,Nqblubh, Nqflua, Nqdwingi, Nqlhalha, Ukahama, Mhboa, Sharabrab, Falup]),

s([Nqblubh, Mhboa], []),
s([Nqrrroah, Ukahama, Nqblubh], []),
s([Nqlhalha, Falup], []),
s([Nqlhalha, Ukahama], []),
s([Nqlhalha, Ukahama, Nqflua], []),
s([Nqflua, Sharabrab], []),
s([Nqblubh, Falup, Nqdwingi], []),
s([Nqflua, Ukahama, Nqdwingi], []),
s([Nqdwingi, Falup, Nqflua], []),
is_set([Nqrrroah, Nqblubh, Nqflua, Nqdwingi, Nqlhalha, Ukahama, Mhboa, Sharabrab, Falup]).  %is_set is True if the List is a proper list without duplicates
```

We defined our grammar with the whole goldfish, shark, swim... before and that works absolutely correctly.

Comment: Something isn't quite making sense here. What's the purpose of the statement, `([sharks, goldfishes, hawks, finches, boys, eat, swim, fly], [Nqrrroah,Nqblubh, Nqflua, Nqdwingi, Nqlhalha, Ukahama, Mhboa, Sharabrab, Falup])`? It doesn't do anything. As far as the error is concerned, it is probably something in `s`, but you haven't shown it.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** Prolog reads top level lists of atoms as instructions to load source files named by those atoms.

---

Prolog reads top-level occurrences of lists of atoms as a command to load a file named by the atom. While this isn't used that often these days, it was once useful as a short hand for loading source files. You could just write,
`['my_file.pl']` to load a database or set of rules. You can try this out yourself by entering the name of a source file enclosed in square brackets into the top level prompt, e.g.

```
?- [my_file].
```

or

```
?- ['my_file.pl'].
```

Now, in your first clause, the first line in the body is

```
([sharks, goldfishes, hawks, finches, boys, eat, swim, fly],
  [Nqrrroah,Nqblubh, Nqflua, Nqdwingi, Nqlhalha, Ukahama, Mhboa, Sharabrab, Falup]),
```

This is equivalent to

```
[sharks, goldfishes, hawks, finches, boys, eat, swim, fly],
[Nqrrroah,Nqblubh, Nqflua, Nqdwingi, Nqlhalha, Ukahama, Mhboa, Sharabrab, Falup]
```

since parentheses do nothing to a conjunction (i.e., `true, false` is equivalent to `(true, false)`. Prolog reads this as a command to load files  named `sharks`, `goldfishes`, etc. and then to load files named `Nqrrroah`, etc. The first error is because there is no file named `sharks` in the current working directory. The second error is because Prolog is expecting a file name, but is instead receiving a free variable.

I'm not sure what you meant this conjunction of lists to be, but there's the root of your errors. :)